# _routeColletion.GetRouteData is null on custom httpmodule

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, sharepoint, httpmodule

I am trying to make an httpmodule that will rewrite the URL in the browser from something like this:

`Paginas/Asesor.aspx?U=JohnSmith&C=23324` to something like this `Paginas/Asesores/JohnSmith`

This is the code I have:

```
public class SPSitiosAsesores : IHttpModule
    {
        #region "IHttpModule Members"
        public void Dispose()
        {
            _routeColletion = null;
        }

        RouteCollection _routeColletion;

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            _routeColletion = new RouteCollection();

            _routeColletion.Add(new Route("Asesor/{Asesores}", new RewriteHandler()));
            _routeColletion.Add(new Route("Asesor.aspx", new BaseHandler()));

            context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);

            _routeColletion.RouteExistingFiles = true;
        }

        void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cont = HttpContext.Current;

            RouteData routeData = _routeColletion.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
            if(routeData != null)
            {
                BaseHandler routeHandler = routeData.RouteHandler as BaseHandler;
                if (routeHandler != null)
                {
                    routeHandler.HandleRoute(routeData);                    
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        private class BaseHandler : IRouteHandler
        {
            #region "IRouteHandler Members"
            public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            #endregion

            public virtual void HandleRoute(RouteData routeData)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter = new UrlFixupFilter(HttpContext.Current.Response.Filter, routeData, 
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority));
            }
        }

        private class UrlFixupFilter : Stream
        {
            private Stream _previousFilter;
            private RouteData _routeData;
            private string _baseUrl;
            public UrlFixupFilter(Stream previousFilter, RouteData routeData, string baseUrl)
            {
                _previousFilter = previousFilter;
                _routeData = routeData;
                _baseUrl = baseUrl;
            }

            #region "Stream Method Overrides"
            public override bool CanRead
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override bool CanSeek
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override bool CanWrite
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override void Flush()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override long Length
            {
                get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
            }

            public override long Position
            {
                get
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
                set
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }

            public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

            public override void SetLength(long value)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            #endregion

            public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
            {
                _previousFilter.Write(replaceUrls(buffer), offset, count);
            }
            private byte[] replaceUrls(byte[] buffer)
            {
                string @string = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                Regex regex = new Regex(@"href.*/Paginas//Asesor\.aspx\?ID=/\d*&C=\w/");

                return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(regex.Replace(@string, delegate(Match match)
                {
                    string format = "href=\"{0}/Asesor/{1}";

                    if (match.Groups[2].Value != "Permalink")
                    {
                        return string.Format(format, _baseUrl, match.Groups[1].Value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return match.Value;
                    }
                }));   
            }
        }

        private class RewriteHandler : BaseHandler
        {
            public override void HandleRoute(RouteData routeData)
            {
                base.HandleRoute(routeData);

                string path = string.Format("/Paginas/Asesor.aspx?U={0}&C={1}", routeData.Values["UserName"], routeData.Values["UserCode"]);
                HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(path);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is in the begin request event:

```
 RouteData routeData = _routeColletion.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```

Can anyone help please? Thanks

Comment: the code is based on this blog post: http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2010/04/implement-friendly-urls-for-sharepoint-blog-sites/

Comment: It would be a whole lot simpler just to use the [IIS URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module) rather than building an `HttpModule` yourself.